ZVS Driver - ElectroBoom
ElectoBoom shared ZVS driver diagram. I don't need large current - more important to me is high output voltage and high frequency.
How to change transistors switching frequency?
List of components:

L1: 12 turns, ~5 cm diameter and ~3.5 cm length, air core;
L2 and L3 core: EPCOS/TDK B64290L0618X038;
C1, 4x capacitors in parallel: Kemet R76IR415050H3J;
C2: 10 uF, 16 V electrolytic;
R1 and R2: 165 ohm, 250 mW;
R3 and R4 (if you use them): 10 kΩ
R5: 47 ohm;
D1 and D2: On-Semi BZX79C15-T50R;
D3 and D4: On-Semi SB1100;
Q1 and Q2: Infineon IRFB7534PBF;
Heatsinks (use thermal grease): CUI Devices HSE-B20254-035H-02



adamssson - Hi, Where did the image come from? (Just saying ElectroBoom isn't enough.) To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). I don't think it applies here, but if the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then add full source details e.g. title, author, page, edition etc. TY

You might also explain the ZVS acronym. Zero Voltage Switch? It doesn't look like one!

@Transistor "ZVS" is Zero Voltage Switching, a common technique to minimize switching loss in resonant converters. It might also be seen as synonymous with this (Baxandall) oscillator circuit, which is widely copied across the internet, the circuit more or less as shown, and the image being copied or redrawn from a few sources mostly. (As need for definitions go, honestly I expect this second meaning to have more common currency with readers than the former.)


How to change transistors switching frequency?

Decrease the value of L1 or C1 or both.
There is a circuit simulator that you can use called CircuitLab. It is available as in the tools above the edit window if you edit your question.
FYI, the Schottky and Zener diodes seem to have reversed part numbers in your parts list. BZX79C15-T50R is a Zener (but is indicated for D1 and D2) while SB1100 is a Schottky (but is indicated for D3 and D4).
I simulated the circuit myself, but with components available for CircuitLab. I discovered that I needed to remove D3, D4 and R3 and R4, otherwise the oscillations died out. I also removed the C2 and R5. My experience with simulation, and with different parts may not be what happens in a real circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here is a time domain simulation of this circuit.


